# Is the sizeof operator needed for malloc?

Tags: c

In this program **(C, not C++)**, why malloc always returns the correct size regardless of the use of the sizeof operator?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *c = malloc(3);
    short *s = malloc(3); /* or malloc(3 * sizeof(short))? */
    int *i = malloc(3);   /* or malloc(3 * sizeof(int))? */
    long *l = malloc(3);  /* or malloc(3 * sizeof(long))? */

    printf("%p\n", c++);
    printf("%p\n", c++);
    printf("%p\n", c++);

    printf("---\n");

    printf("%p\n", s++);
    printf("%p\n", s++);
    printf("%p\n", s++);

    printf("---\n");

    printf("%p\n", i++);
    printf("%p\n", i++);
    printf("%p\n", i++);

    printf("---\n");

    printf("%p\n", l++);
    printf("%p\n", l++);
    printf("%p\n", l++);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0x1e82010 (1 byte)
0x1e82011
0x1e82012
---
0x1e82030 (2 bytes)
0x1e82032
0x1e82034
---
0x1e82050 (4 bytes)
0x1e82054
0x1e82058
---
0x1e82070 (8 bytes)
0x1e82078
0x1e82080
```

Am I missing something?

4.0.4-303.fc22.x86_64
clang version 3.5.0 (tags/RELEASE_350/final)
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

Comment: You're doing address arithmetic; you're not accessing the memory, which is just as well since only 3 bytes have been allocated, so for all except the `char *` part, you are accessing memory out of bounds.

Comment: What you're doing is undefined behavior. The fact that it "appears" to work doesn't make it legal (or valid). You could set those pointers to `NULL` and get the same results.

Comment: How did you determine how much memory malloc has allocated?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: You don't. If it returns a non-null result, it allocated at least as much as you asked it to; don't assume it allocated more. If it returns a null pointer, it didn't allocate anything.

Comment: @Cornstalks, are you sure the behavior is undefined, given that he never dereferences any of the pointers?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yes it is. Pointer arithmetic is defined only within the bounds of an array object. Going past the end of the containing array has undefined behavior, even if the pointer is never dereferenced. (It's legal to compute a pointer *just* past the last element of an array, but dereferencing it has undefined behavior.)

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake. I totally missed the point here. I understand now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 11):

```
long *l = malloc(3);
```

This allocates (or rather attempts to allocate) 3 *bytes*.

Typically `malloc()` will actually allocate more than you request, for alignment and bookkeeping purposes. So after calling `malloc(3)`, you may well be able to get away with storing 3 `long` values in the allocated memory. But it's not guaranteed.

Yes, you do need the `sizeof`.

And the best way to write that is:

```
long *l = malloc(3 * sizeof *l);
```

By using the size of what the pointer points to (`sizeof *l`), you don't have to specify the type `long` twice, and the code won't break if the type changes later.

Even better:

```
long *l = malloc(3 * sizeof *l);
if (l == NULL) {
    /* malloc failed, recover or bail out */
}
```

If you prefer, you can write this as:

```
long *l = malloc(3 * sizeof(*l));
```

but the extra parentheses aren't necessary, size `sizeof` is a unary operator, not a function.

```
printf("%p\n", l++);
printf("%p\n", l++);
printf("%p\n", l++);
```

Incrementing a pointer advances it by the size of the type it points to. `long` is apparently 8 bytes on your system, so this will advance `l` by least 24 bytes, well past the 3 bytes you requested from `malloc`. The result is undefined behavior.

And by incrementing `l`, you've lost the original value returned by `malloc`; you'll need that when it's time to call `free()`.

Finally the `%p` format specifier requires an argument of type `void*`. Passing a different pointer type is likely to "work", but you really should cast it to `void*`:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)l++);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the extra tips.

Comment: Kudos for `long *l = malloc(3 * sizeof *l);` rather than `long *l = malloc(3 * sizeof (long));`

Answer (score 5):

> Am I missing something?

Yes, you are totally missing the point.

You are testing *pointer arithmetic*, which is defined in terms of the size of the pointed-to type.  That has absolutely nothing to do with the amount of memory allocated by `malloc()`, or even whether the pointer in question points to a valid address at all.

Answer (score 4):

Incrementing a pointer increments the stored address by the size of the base type. It does not depend on what the pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score 2):

The number of bytes incremented when you increment a pointer is only based on its type -- e.g. if you increment an `int*` by 1, you'll increment the address by 4 bytes. This has nothing to do with `malloc` or `sizeof` or anything.

You'll find that if you start storing values in those pointers, you'll run into strange behavior, as you haven't allocated enough space to store 3 `short`s, or 3 `int`s, or 3 `long`s.

Answer (score 2):

You have fallen prey to a fallacy.  You are not analyzing what malloc has returned, you are seeing that increment knows how to properly increment the pointer based on the size of the variable type.  Nothing about a malloc call tells you how much RAM was actually allocated.